# What is this "SELECT TRUE" MySQL syntax doing?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I'm going through some of my old unused code, and I cannot find any documentation for this syntax of the select query:

```
    $stmt = $dbh->prepare("SELECT TRUE FROM `users` WHERE `username`= :username LIMIT 1");
$stmt->bindParam(':username', $regUsername);
$stmt->execute();
```

MySQL Docs don't mention anything, and I am unsure of what value it returns... does it simply return '1' if a record matches and '0' if it doesn't?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It selects a row with a single `1` if there's a match, and no row at all if there is no match.

Comment: Why is there no documentation of this that I can find?

Comment: @Antilogical Because it's a regular select. You basically just select TRUE (1) as a value for rows that match your condition. If there is a row, you get a single 1, if there is no row as a result from your condition, you're not getting a row with the value.

Comment: @Antilogical For example, if `SELECT a from b` gives you 10 rows of the value of `a`, then `SELECT 1 FROM b` will give you 10 rows of the value of `1`.

Comment: Okey dokey, thank you very much. I was thinking it might be a reserved word for a bit there.

Comment: where it ll be useful in practical?

Comment: @user1844933 In this case, you could do `SELECT `username` FROM...` instead for more or less the same effect, however `1` or `TRUE` does not need to be changed if your query/table changes to use other field names. It's also a constant so _may_ help the optimizer slightly.

Answer (score 2):

```
TRUE=1  //selects a row with a single 1
and FALSE=0
```

True or False are not reserved in SQL.  Most often when programming you would use a bit and `0 = False while 1 = True.`